# JavaScript radio button score counter

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create basic question game using HTML and JS.
There is a question with three possible answers. If user select correct answer he gets one point and an alert that the answer is correct. If user selects incorrect answer he gets an alert that the answer is incorrect. 
I managed to get the alerts correctly according to what is selected. But i cannot get the counter to increase (it stays always 0). Have no ideas where can be the problem, so I am looking for help here.

```js
var rez = ivertinimas(); 
var suTaskai = "Rezultatas: " + rez;
document.getElementById("rezultatas").innerHTML = suTaskai;
function ivertinimas() {
  var taskai = 0;
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("kalnas");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      var ats = radios[i].value;
        if (ats === "k2") {
          alert("Atsakymas teisingas!");
          taskai++;
        }
        else {
            alert("Atsakymas neteisingas. Teisingas atsakymas yra K2.")
        }
     break;
    }
  }
    return taskai;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="title">Klausimų žaidimas</h1>
  <h3>Už kiekveiną teisingą atsakymą duodamas vienas taškas.</h3>
  <h3 id="rezultatas"></h3>
  <h4>Koks yra antras pagal aukštį kalnas pasaulyje?</h4>
  <form id="klausimai" onsubmit="ivertinimas()">
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="everestas">Everestas<br>
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="k2">K2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="leipkalnis">Liepkalnis<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Pateikti atsakymą">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: define your counter outside of the function

Comment: your form is submitting which is causing the page to disappear.

Comment: I think you should not you use form this. You can simply update the value with client side javascript.

Comment: "taskai = 0;" should outside of ivertinimas() function block. Otherwise every time taskai starting from zero and losing prev counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example (had to remove the form so that I can show the counter going up)

```js
var taskai = 0;
var rez = ivertinimas(); 
var suTaskai = "Rezultatas: " + rez;
document.getElementById("rezultatas").innerHTML = suTaskai;
function ivertinimas() {
  
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("kalnas");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      var ats = radios[i].value;
        if (ats === "k2") {
          alert("Atsakymas teisingas!");
          taskai++;
          var somevar = "Rezultatas: " + taskai;
          document.getElementById("rezultatas").innerHTML = somevar;
        }
        else {
            alert("Atsakymas neteisingas. Teisingas atsakymas yra K2.")
        }
     break;
    }
  }
    return taskai;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="title">Klausimų žaidimas</h1>
  <h3>Už kiekveiną teisingą atsakymą duodamas vienas taškas.</h3>
  <h3 id="rezultatas"></h3>
  <h4>Koks yra antras pagal aukštį kalnas pasaulyje?</h4>
  
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="everestas">Everestas<br>
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="k2">K2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="leipkalnis">Liepkalnis<br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="ivertinimas()" value="Pateikti atsakymą">
  
</div>
```

All I did was to put the counter outside the function, and also add in the dynamic update of the result on the HTML. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

the var taskai have to be global

```
    var rez = ivertinimas(); 
var suTaskai = "Rezultatas: " + rez;
var taskai
document.getElementById("rezultatas").innerHTML = suTaskai;
function ivertinimas() {
var radios = document.getElementsByName("kalnas");
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
    var ats = radios[i].value;
        if (ats === "k2") {
        alert("Atsakymas teisingas!");
        taskai++;
        }
        else {
            alert("Atsakymas neteisingas. Teisingas atsakymas yra K2.")
        }
    break;
    }
}
    return taskai;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The counter needs to be global and the execution of the function should not be triggered by onsubmit.

```js
let taskai = 0;

function update(counter) {
  var suTaskai = "Rezultatas: " + counter;
  document.getElementById("rezultatas").innerHTML = suTaskai;
}

function ivertinimas() {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("kalnas");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      var ats = radios[i].value;
      if (ats === "k2") {
        //alert("Atsakymas teisingas!");
        update(++taskai);
      } else {
        alert("Atsakymas neteisingas. Teisingas atsakymas yra K2.")
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="title">Klausimų žaidimas</h1>
  <h3>Už kiekveiną teisingą atsakymą duodamas vienas taškas.</h3>
  <h3 id="rezultatas"></h3>
  <h4>Koks yra antras pagal aukštį kalnas pasaulyje?</h4>
  <form id="klausimai">
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="everestas">Everestas<br>
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="k2">K2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="leipkalnis">Liepkalnis<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Pateikti atsakymą" onclick="ivertinimas(); return false">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and awful solution for your problem.

```js
var rez = 0
var suTaskai = 'Rezultatas: <span id="result"></span>';
document.getElementById("rezultatas").innerHTML = suTaskai;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = rez;
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function ivertinimas() {
  var taskai = +document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
  var radios = document.getElementsByName("kalnas");
  for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      var ats = radios[i].value;
      if (ats === "k2") {
        alert("Atsakymas teisingas!");
        taskai++;
      } else {
        alert("Atsakymas neteisingas. Teisingas atsakymas yra K2.")
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = taskai;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="title">Klausimų žaidimas</h1>
  <h3>Už kiekveiną teisingą atsakymą duodamas vienas taškas.</h3>
  <h3 id="rezultatas"><span id="result"></span></h3>
  <h4>Koks yra antras pagal aukštį kalnas pasaulyje?</h4>
  <div id="klausimai">
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="everestas">Everestas<br>
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="k2">K2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="kalnas" value="leipkalnis">Liepkalnis<br>
    <button id="button" onclick="ivertinimas()">Pateikti atsakymą</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should define your `var taskai = 0;` outside of the function, you're calling.
Please note however, that defining global variables is not always a good idea.

For more info see: https://gist.github.com/hallettj/64478

Comment: maybe put credit to the person who commented that minutes before you?